# using Set uid to run a root command from non-root user

Tags: shell, permissions, executable, setuid

Consider the following two files. `summarize`'s executable UID bit has been set, so that another user belonging to another group can execute the summarize executable that uses the customers.dat file.

```
-rw-------  steve  sales  customers.dat
-rwsr-xr-x  steve  sales  summarize
```

Now consider the following two files:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root   root   5974 May 17 13:53 1.out
-rwsrwsrwx 1 root   root   5970 May 17 14:03 a.out
```

Both are executables, and I want that some other user runs `a.out`, which calls `1.out` within itself using the `system("./1.out");` call.

But I am always getting permission denied error

```
sh: ./1.out: Permission denied
```

To me, both scenarios look the same. Why do I get the permission denied error?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Extract from [Set-UID Programs and Vulnerabilities](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Set_UID.pdf):

> – Recall that system() invokes /bin/sh first. In Fedora, it execv /bin/sh with arguments
>     "sh", "-c" and the user provided string.
>
> – In Fedora, /bin/sh (actually bash) ignores the Set-UID bit option. Therefore, when invok-
>     ing system (cmd) in a Set-UID program, cmd will not be executed with the root privilege,
>     unless cmd itself is a Set-UID program. The following code in bash drops the Set-UID bit.
>     Actually, I cannot think of any legitimate reason why we need to allow Set-UID shell program.
>     Fedora is doing the right thing; many other Unix OSes have not done this.

According to this 1.out is not set uid and a.out drops privileges before executing it.

Comment: so isnt there a way to code an ececutable that has root privileges which invokes other commands that are supposed to be run under root permissions on its behalf?

Comment: I imagine (not tested) that making 1.out set uid as well would accomplish what you want.  Whether or not that's secure is something I can't judge.  One problem I can imagine is that the user who's able to run a.out would be able to call 1.out directy.  There might be bigger security problems than this though.

Comment: You can certainly exec(3) programs.

Comment: Your permissions on the SUID executable include write permissions for other people, any halfway sane kernel will refuse to run that.